How appreciated is "Part III" in the US?
I will complete an MSc in physics, including a thesis, this year.
I have received an offer for a 9 month taught math master's course at Cambridge called Part III, although I don't yet have a funding offer for it, sadly. Some funding sources are available but it is competitive.
My main reason to take this course (beyond the degree itself) is to improve my chances of being accepted to a PhD in physics at Oxford or Cambridge.
Yet I also wonder how much this course is appreciated in the US and if having done it will improve my chances of being accepted for a PhD in top graduate physics schools there were I to apply there as well.
For my doctoral programme, I aim to research topics such GR, QFT, string theory, quantum gravity.

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488360/mathematical-tripos-part-iii-at-cambridge-university

Note that Cambridge likes a lot to have their own naming and idiosyncrasies, but Part III is just a MSc in Mathematics.

@AnderBiguri It's an MMath for students who completed their undergrad at Cambridge, and a MASt for students who didn't. Cambridge doesn't award an MSc in Mathematics, and even the undergraduate course is a BA rather than a BSc.

@kaya3 I know, I work there :) But Cambridge idiosyncrasies aside, its not materially different to an MSc in mathematics, that was my point. If you go to a different university and you get a BSc in Maths and then a MSc in Maths, you have an equivalent degree. Particularly to apply to a PhD. Of course, the name of the uni matters, I guess, and given how hard Part III is, im sure it helps. Also the difference between a BA and a BSc in mathematics is none, its an undergrad in maths. Particularly, again, when talking about PhD applications.

Part III of the Tripos is reasonably well known amongst professional mathematicians. I can't comment on physics. Good marks would surely boost your competitiveness for PhD slots in math.
Having taken one of Oxford's similarly pitched courses 8 years ago or so, here's a broadly applicable set of logistical anecdotes related to subsequent US PhD applications. They all flow downstream from the fact that Part III starts in October and US PhD applications are often due in December.

You will have to prepare and send off PhD applications alongside some of the hardest segments of the Masters course.
By the time PhD applications are due, you will have no marks from Part III nor will you have new recommendation letters because there is not enough time. The course is correspondingly unlikely to boost your PhD applications very much in the immediate term.


Thank you, can I also ask if you know whether part III or Oxford mathematical physics MSc will be more appreciated by universities? I tend to think that part III from information available online, but I would be happy to hear from someone who studied there

@ziv This site has a general rule not to rank programs etc., born out of reasoning that the Q&A format doesn't really handle this well. If you're an undergrad now, why not talk to a professor in your current program about these questions instead? On this particular point: I am a mathematician and took a math course at Ox, so I'm especially unable to guess what the physicists are looking for.

I think Part III is quite common amongst US students nowadays, and is thus well-known to graduate admissions committees.  Probably the effect on your application will be good, since if nothing else it shows you are serious about studying mathematics; a school can also reasonably expect you to be considerably better prepared coming after a year at Part III than when you finished your BA.  So if one of your issues was a weak curriculum as a BA student (as opposed to poor grades or weak letters), then Part III could help quite a bit.  On the other hand, I wouldn't count on a dramatic change in your graduate school admissions, in part because as you note, you won't have your grades or a strong recommendation from Part III in hand when you apply for graduate schools the next time around. I wouldn't worry about the fact that Part III is not research based; obviously doing research before starting graduate school is great, but most graduate schools in the US are not really expecting you to have done much in the way of it beforehand, or to be even close to ready to start when you enter.
I think if money is no object, then Part III is probably as good as anything else you might do for having a strong graduate application in the coming cycle.  EDIT: I should probably also say that a matter of substance (as opposed to application strategy), Part III is probably on average better than spending a year as a grad student at a random respectable grad program in the US, since it will bring you into contact with a wide variety of other students and ideas.
However, I think you should weigh that next to the possibility of starting graduate school at one of your lower preferences, and then trying to transfer after a year, or when you get a master's degree.  There's no guarantee this will work, but the same can be said of Part III.  If you've been offered funded admission at a respectable school in the US, and would have to pay your own way at Part III, I would look hard at whether you think it's worth the money.
EDIT: I wouldn't count on the "glamour" of Cambridge itself to have a strong effect.  I honestly don't know how selective Part III is (maybe someone who knows can comment.), so I wouldn't rely on assuming that admissions committees will consider it as such.  There's some psychological "band-wagon" effect where getting one prestigious position reinforces getting others, but it won't work if the substance isn't there. Getting a BA from Harvard or MIT is helpful for getting into graduate school (if you have a strong record) because an admissions committee is more confident that getting an A in math class at Harvard really means something, and that a professor at Harvard has a lot of experience with talented undergraduates and thus can speak with some certainty about what it takes to succeed in graduate school.  So, if you went to Part III, got good scores on your exams and got a strong recommendation from a professor there, that could strengthen your application a lot as a "second opinion" reinforcing the recommendations and grades you have from your BA.  However, as discussed, those would only be available for the fall 2016 admission cycle, not 2015.  One possibility is to see about accepting one of your safety schools with a deferment to go to Cambridge, going to Part II in 2014-5, going to the safety school in 2015 and applying for transfer in 2016 or 2017 if you're unhappy there.
One piece of information we're lacking is what your "lower preferences" are (don't put too much stock in USNW rankings, but they help to be concrete in a discussion like this).  It makes a big difference whether we're talking about a school in the rank ~25 (like UCSD), ~50 (like UVA) or ~100 (for example, South Carolina).  In the former case, I'd say it's a waste of time to try to try to move up unless you go and are miserable, whereas in the latter it makes a certain kind of sense.
LATER EDIT: Incidentally, yes, given that your undergraduate grades are already "baked in," the main things you can still hope to change are your letters, and also your GRE scores if those were bad.

From your answer, I suppose then the more important thing for me is to secure a stronger letter in the next 6 months. I will have to weigh the financial options. One last question: You say a potential benefit of taking the course is that it shows I'm serious about studying mathematics. I was wondering, does it also impress admissions people in any way? For example, if the first thing one sees is that the applicant is from Harvard, you might think there is a decent chance the applicant is a strong student. Does Part III have a similar effect? Thank you for your answer Ben.

@Craig I added more about your question to my answer.

"I honestly don't know how selective Part III is" -- it's fairly selective: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~twk/PartIII.pdf, "... normally require First Class Honours from students coming from other British universities ... you should be able to profit from
Part III if you are in the top 10% of mathematicians graduating in your country". I guess the questioner's previous unfavourable PhD responses already had the same information that Cambridge used to accept him for Part III. If they rejected due to lack of Master's-level study, then Part III is exactly that by international standards.

@SteveJessop I actually read that earlier.  I don't read "you should be able to profit from Part III if..." as the same as "we will only admit you to Part III if..." as synonymous.  Of course, I'm sure it isn't all that easy to get into Part III, but I wouldn't take it as a sign that somebody has a really strong file, like I would someone getting into, say, Harvard.  That was also meant to suggest that other people may not know how to interpret it and thus won't put a lot of weight on it.

@BenWebster: fair enough, it's all about how people interpret it after all, not how selective the course really is. But given what I know of Cambridge and the language of UK universities, I would not expect a course to admit someone if, in the opinion of the admissions people, they don't meet the criteria to benefit from it. Strictly speaking those criteria are stated as sufficient but not necessary anyway, so it's ambiguous however you cut it :-) "Normally require First Class honours" is an indicator, but of course you can prove that to the PhD program with or without Cambridge's say-so.

Also I don't know this, but based on how the MMath course I did at Oxford works, I suspect that if you get into the Cambridge undergraduate course, and do reasonably well on it (on course for a first), and want to take Part III, then you'll get a place. That is just a guess though, I don't know for sure that they don't apply a serious selection procedure to their own undergrads. So you might well consider that an indicator that although it's fairly selective (this is maths at Cambridge after all), it's not hyper-selective.

... the reason I guess this is because top UK universities are keen for students to take the MMath, and this is the form Cambridge offers it in. Getting off topic but the reason they're keen is the state of maths education to 18: for example some students now arrive at university without any abstract algebra. So the pace of bachelor's degrees has slackened. The MMath is, in response, a "proper maths degree". Cambridge may be different but usually it doesn't imply genius, just that you can do something non-trivial with homotopy groups (or whatever subjects you pursue in the 4th year).

My best offer was at a school that usually ranks between 10th and 20th. Could you elaborate on why it is a waste of time to try to get into a better school (5th-10th in USNews say) in that situation? Is it because it is very unlikely for some reason, or because the improvement would be overall negligible in the long term?

Briefly: while I'm sure it is better on average to go to top 10ish school than one in the 10-20 range, I don't think the difference is large enough to justify the effort, when the chance of successfully "trading up" is low.  There just aren't very many seats in top ten programs (on the order of 200 per year) and you're competing against the whole world.  The benefit is also uncertain: not having attended any of these schools, you have no idea what's going to work personally for you.

If you've gotten a funded offer at a school which is generally regarded as top 20, unless you have some very specific reason not to go, try it out for a year.  You won't have to pay, the education should be a similar quality to Cambridge, and you might find you really like it.  If not, you can always get a masters and try to get in somewhere else, though I think if you want to get in somewhere top 10, you've got to really knock their socks off.

I am just finishing Part III after doing an MSc in my home country and my focus has been on the topics in theoretical physics that you listed. As others have pointed out, by the time applications are due, you will have no grades from the course since all assessment is at the end of the year. Therefore you are essentially trading on the reputation of the university alone. In the UK and Europe, Part III is held in high regard and so you will be at the top of the pack for PhD applications here but note that there are ~70 theoretical physics students in Part III so you'll be competing with them for the best places. Of those 70 students, ~10 get offers for PhDs in DAMTP HEP/GR and probably less for Oxford math HEP/GR (since you compete with more people outside Part III).
Having spoken to people in Part III who have applied for US PhD programmes, Part III will definitely help your chances, but there is still a large bias towards those who did their undergraduate at a reputable US institution. The only students I know who were accepted by a US programme had come from good US schools previously. This is only what I have observed from a small sample size and many in Part III just don't want to go to the US.
For what it's worth, I got everything I wanted out of Part III. It has been great training for a PhD in quantum gravity, the courses were awesome and I could trade on the reputation of the university to get the PhD position that I wanted. At the same time, I've found it really stressful. You begin the year worrying about PhD applications, then you work through the first holiday to prepare for the Cambridge PhD early offers test (HEP and GR only), then the rest of the year is spent worrying about getting the grades necessary to keep your PhD offer if you were lucky enough to get one.
Despite all that, doing Part III will most likely have a great impact on your career in theoretical physics or outside of physics and it really comes down to whether you can stomach the cost and a year of uncertainty.

Thank you very much for the useful information. Can I ask what skills you need to excel in the HEP/GR PhD exams? Do they check your overall understanding in physics and mathematics? Or do they specifically examine your skills in GR/QFT, relying on the fact that many students already have some background in these subjects? Is there a place where I can find more information on this exams?

Also, do you know how many of this ~10 successful PhD candidates get funding for the PhD?

I haven't seen any information on the early offers test online. It's entirely based on coursework in Michaelmas term. There is a question for each of the big theoretical physics courses (GR, QFT, Symmetries particles and fields, cosmology) and you answer 2 or 3 questions in 3 hours. Best way to start preparing would be to start looking at the course material. e.g. the QFT course is almost always based on David Tong's lecture notes which are publicly available.

I think funding is not a big problem for those who get offers in DAMTP HEP/GR but it can be a struggle for international students applying to other UK institutions.

I see... And are the exams done with open materials?

No, all exams in Part III are closed book exams. They tend to be very heavy on book work. It's the tradition of the tripos apparently.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

When I took Part III exams (in 2010), the exams I took were all closed book, but exams for some of the other Part III courses which my classmates took were open book. I think an astrophysics or cosmology course was one example. I don't know how this is in 2024, but there is no long-standing strict rule preventing professors from setting open book exams.

As a physicist who has moved between the US and UK, and thus has experience with both systems, my advice is that part III (or the equivalent at Oxford) it not really a good idea if your main goal is to go to the US for a PhD.
First, there are the logistical issues, as user176372 mentioned in their answer.
Secondly (and most importantly), it may not help much, even if somehow you are able to use your part III results for your application to US PhD programs. The US and the UK actually have very different "cultures" when it comes to PhD admissions.  The US is very research-focused: what matters most are projects that you've done, letters of recommendation from professors that you've worked with, and any publications you already have.  The UK, on the other hand, is very coursework and exam-focused, probably a legacy of the tripos at Cambridge and the surrounding culture.
For example, performing very well (i.e. ranking top ~5 or so in your cohort) in Part III (or the equivalent at Oxford), will almost guarantee  you a PhD position anywhere in the UK; but performing extremely well on courses/exams will not be a huge boost to a US PhD application, unless you have research experience to support it.  In fact, doing a Part III (or the Oxford version) might be a net negative in terms of going to the US afterwards, since you will have to spend a whole year on classes with no time for projects or research.
Third, it could be a waste of time. Most US PhD programs have a required coursework component that cannot be (completely) skipped, even if you already have taken similar courses or already hold a Masters degree. Since you already have an MSc, if you do Part III + US PhD, you will end up basically doing three (!) masters in physics. This is not the best use of time: the only way to advance your career as a physicist is to do research: it is necessary to have basic knowledge foundation, of course, but after a point more coursework becomes a waste of time.

If you are dead-set on doing your PhD in Cambridge/Oxford, then go for the Part III.  Otherwise, since you already have an MSc, it would be a better idea to apply to PhD programs in the US, and also in continental Europe. (Germany/Switzerland etc. are also great places to do a PhD in physics, and may be the best for you as it would allow you to directly get into research).  You can also apply to PhD programs in the UK, although as you already know, your ability to get into Oxbridge might be limited by not having the Part III/masters—but it is not impossible; I know several people doing their PhD in theoretical physics in Oxbridge without having first done the masters from the same institution.

note: my field is condensed matter/quantum information theory. What I say here should apply to high energy theory as well. Pure math (and the parts of physics truly bordering on pure math) will be a bit different, as in there (I think) there is more emphasis on courses/exams/competitions, even in the US.

@Trunk theory, but thanks for the reminder. see the edit

I was going to write an answer, from the perspective of a high-energy theorist in the US, but this one already says what I would have said. Part III is certainly well-known, but (apart from the fact that you'll have barely started when you apply, unless you have a gap year in between) the downside is that we are mostly looking for research experience, and Part III doesn't help with that. Letters from the UK are often not useful because they just comment on relative rank in coursework, not research.

Where are you now? I am guessing not at either Cambridge nor Oxford. You will have a master in physics already in time but not from either of those universities(?). Do you want a second master in mathematics because that is what Part III is! Are you sure that your current course does not already covered those topics that you will be studying in Part III? There are options in Part III that you can always pick new courses to study, of course. Do you want the prestige of being attached to Cambridge or Oxford because if you don't have funding, it will cost you a small fortune for that. But then if there is a specific someone that you want to work with there, you should try communicate with that person to see how likely you can continue to do a Ph.D with him/her after Part III as well as the potential funding for the Ph.D.. It will be an obstacle course for you. If you can get the funding, then I would do the Part III especially if you can take new topics that have not been covered by your currnet course. On the other hand, if you cannot find any monetary support, then you will have to decide. I would say that it is still helpful with a Part III under your belt if you want to look for a Ph.D. position in the U.S afterwards.

Thank you, Yes I know it is another master's. Apart from my will to research with specific professors there, it cover topics that are almost not researched in my country at all. I am sure that this course really fits me well, but having to spend 50k pounds makes it hard to evaluate, so I am trying to understand if it has other benefits

Yes... And the most frustrating thing is that I can study in my country for free with 2k pounds fellowship per month, the problem is that the research topics are not exactly what I want
